# How to link LoRaWAN Server with WSO2 IoT through MQTT

Tags: mqtt, lorawan

I have been working on creating my private LoRaWAN network using some nodes with A Dragino Sheild and a LG01 Gateway, so far I have been successful in sending the data to this Open Source Server https://github.com/gotthardp/lorawan-server/.

However this server lacks many things including Data analytics and storage, but it can communicate with an external server using MQTT. So lately I have found a solution called WSO2 IoT http://wso2.com/iot which can be used as an MQTT broker but I wasn't successful in understanding how to create my own device to link it with the LoRaWAN server. Can you please help me to understand how this server works and how to connect them?

Answer (score 5):

WSO2 IoT server itself can be used for your purpose without a problem. You don't need to integrate lorawan-server and use WSO2 server as a MQTT broker here.

I was able to successfully try out their Raspberry pi sample. There they explain how to use their MQTT broker to establish the connection between the Raspberry pi and the WSO2 IoT server. They do have data analytics capabilities and support major databases like H2, MySQL, Oracle etc. Refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/WSO2+IoT+Server+Analytics)
 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/WSO2+IoT+Server+Analytics) for more details.

What this sample simply does is;
WSO2 IoT Server provides a sample Raspberry pi agent (we can customize it as we want). This Pi agent publish temperature sensor data to the MQTT broker and server picks up those data and use for analytics. Also from server side we can send commands to the Raspberry Pi too. In the sample they provide, they allow us to on/off an LED bulb which does the same thing where server publish certain data to a MQTT topic and Raspberry Pi agent listen to that topic and picks up the command and executes it. 
You can see more information about this [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Raspberry+Pi) (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Raspberry+Pi).

Likewise they have allow anyone to write any custom device types using the set of API they have provided. Refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type) (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type). Also they have provided a Maven Archetype in order to create our own device type plugin. Refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+the+Maven+Archetype)
 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+the+Maven+Archetype).

Answer (score 4):

Like stated in answer of your previous question [How can I interface a LoraWan network with MQTT?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/how-can-i-interface-a-lorawan-network-with-mqtt) about MQTT and LoraWan, one device can be member in both,  but both sides do not have to know about each others.

Connect the server that successfully gets the LoraWan data now to Ethernet cable or WiFi and send MQTT to WSO2. It is that LoraWan endpoint server whose responsibility is to find the MQTT destination based on MQTT subscription from WSO2 side.

You should not need any other external device (ok, a WiFi shield maybe).